# Multiple Private Pod with single Repo but different branches Release Failed

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podspec

I am developing N number of private pods some of them are added as `dependency` to other private pods but released in their respective branch. For Example.

`LibA` uses `LibB` as dependency. Both libs are private and having same repo but different branches as follows

Branch of LibA => `release/lib_a`

Branch of LibB => `release/lib_b`

LibB is release successfully on `release/lib_b` branch as it doesn't have any private pod dependency.
But when we want to release `LibA` which is using another private pod on same repo but different branch it gives error while performing `pod spec lint`.

### How i am using lint?

```
pod spec lint --use-libraries --allow-warnings --no-clean --sources='https://github.com/Libraries/private_library_repo.git'
```

When above command is executed it tries to fetch `LibB` but failed to find source because this command tries to find the specification of `LibB` on master branch of repo `https://github.com/Libraries/private_library_repo.git` but `LibB` is not released on master branch instead its released on `release/lib_b`.

Is there any way to specify dependent pod branch with url while pod `lint` & `push`